# Selecting specific value from column resulted from sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written a query which returns the result in single column and the result is like below.

**Attribute Names**

MERGE({116288}, {116226}, {116292}, {116249}, {116253})

MERGE({116287}, {116225}, {116291}, {116248}, {116252})

... 
...

I want to get only integer value from this column.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which is it mysql or sql-server-2008? Can't be both

Comment: sql-server-2008 it is

Comment: You mean you have a query that returns data combined like this and now you want another query to extract from the combined results?

Comment: Yes , I have a query which returns above rows in sql server .. now I want to use this rows (integers only) as where IN (this integers) condition of another query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best solution. But you could do this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(AttributeNames VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
    VALUES
    ('MERGE({116288}, {116226}, {116292}, {116249}, {116253})'),
    ('MERGE({116287}, {116225}, {116291}, {116248}, {116252})')
```

**Split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),
         LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Then the query like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(tbl2.Data AS INT)
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(split.Data,'{',''),'}',''),
            'MERGE(',''),')','')
            )as Data
        FROM
            dbo.Split(tbl.AttributeNames,',') as split
    ) AS tbl2
```